# Magento 2: Intercept controller's JSON response

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, json, interceptor

I'm trying to intercept a controller returning a JSON object of `Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json` class. The problem is that no matter if I use a plugin or a preference to "catch" the controller response right after it's created to do what I want with it, I always end up with this `Json` object, and its only public method inherited from `Magento\Framework\Controller\AbstractResult` is the `renderResult` method (apart from some setters, which won't help me at all).The JSON string is also a protected property, so I can't access it directly.

So, how can I get the JSON string from the response object? Of course, I could just replicate some of the controller's logic that creates it and use that instead, but I'm trying to avoid this method if possible.

I'm using the develop branch. I based my code on the 0be91a5 commit (Merge pull request #14 from magento-vanilla/PR), but I checked the latest commit (currently it's 74f9337 Merge pull request #81 from magento-firedrakes/MAGETWO-44741) and there are no changes in the `Json` and `AbstractResult` classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json has two public methods for work with data. You can add plugin on their methods to modify json related data:

```
class \MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Result\JsonPlugin {
   public function beforeSetData($subject, $data, $cycleCheck = false, $options = []) 
   {
       return [ 'data' => $data, 'metadata' => 'sdsd'];
   }
   public function beforeSetJsonData($subject, $jsonData)
   {  
        return '{"data": ' . $jsonData . , ', "metadata": []}';
   }
```